# Android SQL get item and the item before and after in a SQL column

Tags: android, sql, android-sqlite

I have a SQL database in Android which has a table with values:

```
ID VAL 
1 5 
2 12 
3 8 
4 11 
5 1 
6 22 
7 20 
8 40
9 5
```

I want to write an SQL query where I put in the `ID 7` and get out `12`, `20` and `22`. I want the neighbors determined based on `VAL`. It's possible that numbers in val appear multiple times.
How do I do this?

Comment: `Select ID,VAL from table_name where ID between ( ID-1,ID+1 );`

Comment: @Kedarnath I'm pretty sure that you give you in this example 22, 20 and 40 (Id 6, Id 7 and Id 8). Do you really think it will return something different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

```sql
WITH yourvalue AS
(
  SELECT val FROM t WHERE id = 7
),
downvalue AS
(
  SELECT val 
  FROM t 
  WHERE val < (SELECT val FROM yourvalue)
  ORDER BY val DESC
  OFFSET 0 ROWS
  FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY
),
upvalue AS
(
  SELECT val 
  FROM t 
  WHERE val > (SELECT val FROM yourvalue)
  ORDER BY val
  OFFSET 0 ROWS
  FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY
)
select * from yourvalue
UNION
select * from downvalue
UNION
select * from upvalue
```

Output is: 12, 20, 22

I was able to test this only with MS SQL Server 2012. I believe that this is ANSI SQL, but it seems that SQLite does not like the syntax OFFSET/FETCH. So you can try to change from  `OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY` to `LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0`.